# Eclipse Build Automatically cannot be checked in preferences

Tags: java, eclipse

Im using Eclipse 2022-06, and Build Automatically is unchecked in preferences (see picture below). Problem is that even when I check it, when I restart Eclipse it remains unchecked.

Is there a way to set this up in a properties file?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `description.autobuilding` property in the `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` file in the workspace `.metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory controls this.

Comment: I added `description.autobuilding=1` to the file, restarted Eclipse, but the checkbox is still empty. Is this a defect?

Comment: Valid values are `true` or `false`, but the default if it is missing is `true` anyway. Probably something else going on here.

Comment: `description.autobuilding=true` didn't work either

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. A plugin that you have installed might do this. When automatically building is turned off and Eclipse is closed, does `.metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` contains `description.autobuilding=false`? If yes, than it won't be remain unchecked, but something turns it off on startup (but maybe for reasons). In this case, show what you have in the preferences _General > Startup and Shutdown_.

Comment: I add `description.autobuilding=true` to the file, then start Eclipse, and the checbox is unchecked. Then I open the file, and the line disappeared. I added to the question a screenshot of Startup and Shutdown

Comment: Please tell whether there is `description.autobuilding=true` or `description.autobuilding=false` for both cases, when the checkbox is checked and when it is not checked after Eclipse is closed and not running. Do not edit the file, just use the UI, exit Eclipse and then look into the file. In addition, try to uncheck everything in _General > Startup and Shutdown_. You might also try it with a fresh workspace.

Comment: If I check the checkbox and then close Eclipse, in the file the line disappears. I also tried unchecking everything from Startup and Shutdown, and the problem persists.

Comment: Eclipse saves only those preferences that differ from default. So, when you check it, it disappears, because it's the default. But what is in the file, when you uncheck it and then close Eclipse, before re-starting Eclipse? I would assume that there is `description.autobuilding=false` and this would mean, that the preference is saved correctly, but reverted on startup (maybe by a plugin you have installed). Hence the question.

Comment: Yes, the preference is saved correctly,  I can see it either `description.autobuilding=false` or nothing depending on whether the checkbox is empty or not. But when the checkbox is checked and the preference is not in the file, when I start Eclipse the checkbox in the preference is unchecked and also the menu option in Project -> Build Automatically.

Comment: Same issue here... did you ever got it working?
Fresh new workspace has the same problem.

Comment: No resolution, I still turn on manually `build automatically` every time I start eclipse

Comment: @RomuloDiniz Most likely this is done on startup by a plugin you have installed. It should be easy for someone who facing this issue to track down this plugin by uninstalling one plugin at a time or, the other way around, installing those additional plugins one by one into a fresh Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger I uninstall all the plugins and still have the problem

Comment: So how can the issue be reproduced with which Eclipse IDE package and a fresh workspace? Do you get an error when you change the file permissions of `.metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` to read-only?

Comment: I tried to change the file to read only, I don't get any errors

Comment: @howlger the issue remains if I use a fresh Eclipse install, fresh workspace too, so it's not plugin related.

Comment: @RomuloDiniz I cannot reproduce it. So with which IDE package (there are several) of Eclipse 2022-09 (which is the current version) running Eclipse with which Java (there are several versions and several implementations) are you facing this issue on which operating system (there are several here as well)? Opening Eclipse with a fresh and empty workspace, changing the setting, exiting Eclipse and restarting Eclipse is enough to reproduce this issue on your machine, right?

Comment: @howlger as I mentioned on my answer, this issue was fixed on the new Eclipse 2022-09 version. I couldn't solve the problem on the 2022-06, so it's clear to me it was an error in some lib.

Comment: @RomuloDiniz Okay, fine. All issues I reported have been fixed too.

Answer (score 1):

As expected, this extremely odd and annoying behavior was fixed on the new Eclipse 2022-09. Other annoyances are fixed too, like a freeze when copying contents. Just update it and be happy again.